# PostgreSQL 'Sever closed the connection unexpectedly'

Tags: windows, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using Psycopg2 to insert into a local PostgreSQL database, however since upgrading my PC to windows 10 I keep getting the following error:

> psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
>     This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.

Sometimes the insert is successful, but can take a few attempts to do it. Also when accessing the database through pgadmin III I also get the same error messages when navigating through databases on the server.

I don't get any issues when running this on windows 7 - are there any solutions to this issue?